# My Passport HDD didn't get enough power, then wouldn't initialize. Now, it won't even show up

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1

My WD Passport didn't get enough power, so it wouldn't load anything. It showed up in Disk Management and Device manager as a 0MB drive that was "Not initialized". When I tried to initialize it, windows threw a generic "Failed to initialize due to an error" MessageBox.

Now, it won't even load. When I first plug it into my computer, I get this, but that's it:

[image]

I can hear it (try to) start up and the light blinks, but nothing happens past then.

It doesn't show up in diskmgmt.msc, device manager or Windows Explorer.

However, when I plug it in I see an "Unknown device" that is stopped, saying "Windows has stopped this device because it has reported problems" and giving [error 43](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725873(v=ws.10).aspx)

**How do I fix this so I can access the files on this hard drive again?**

Comment: Have you restarted your computer and tried it again? You may want to try downloading and writing a Linux LiveCD (Ubuntu, for example) as it may be able to read the contents. It may prompt Windows to start reading it again.

Comment: Try, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rksCTVFtjM4 then http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725873(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Plug your external drive into a external USB hub, plug that into the power then into your computer. Hope this helps.